# Not able to push notification with XMPP protocol

Tags: php, push-notification, xmpp

I am trying to push notification with XMPP protocol using `php`. The code that I am trying is :

```
<?php
include 'XMPPHP/XMPP.php';
set_time_limit(0);

echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();

$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com',5235,   'senderid@gcm.googleapis.com', 'serverapikey','xmpphp','gcm.googleapis.com','true', 'info');
echo 'before try';
try {

$conn->connect();

echo 'after connect';
$conn->presence($status='Controller available.');

//$conn->processUntil(array('session_start', 'roster_received'));

//echo 'payload is '.$payload;

//$conn->presence($status='Controller available.');


$msg =" <message id=\"\">
  <gcm xmlns=\"google:mobile:data\">

    \"to\" : \"regId\",

\"message_id\":\"m-1366082849205\" 
      \"data\":
      {
          \"hello\":\"world\"
      },
      \"time_to_live\":\"600\"

  }
  </gcm>
</message>";

 $conn->message('senderid@gcm.googleapis.com', $msg);

$conn->disconnect();

} catch(Exception $e) {
die($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

I am able to connect and send notification with `http`. But I want to  do that using `xampp` protocol.Please let me know how to implement this.